# Set UIImageView as background - Swift 4

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I want to set a background image behind everything that already exists in the view.

I tried :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "bg-img")
    backgroundImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
}
```

But it didn't work (it didn't even add the img). So I imported the ImageView component and added the image using the Xcode GUI and it did add the image but is on top of everything. I have tried several Stack Overflow answers (that's where I get the above code from), but I didn't have any luck.

My folder structure looks like this:

[image]

My image is inside the Assets.xcassets folder.

**UPDATE:**
I restarted Xcode and my code worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the subviews' frames in `viewDidLoad` is not a good practice because subviews aren't yet correctly placed at that point. You should set the frames of subviews in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, which is called after the self.view and it's subviews are correctly laid out.

Your ViewController:

```
var backgroundImage: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.backgroundImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "bg-img"))
    self.backgroundImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    self.view.insertSubview(self.backgroundImage, at: 0)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    self.backgroundImage.frame = self.view.bounds
}
```

Comment: But he is setting the frame to the screen bounds which i assume is available on `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I think you are actually right. I tried sj-r's code without putting `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and still worked

Comment: very weird, I restarted xcode, I tried my original code and it worked

Comment: Setting subview's frame in viewDidLoad is discouraged because technically, the view and its subviews are not laid out yet. For instance, if you rotate your device, my code will adapt to it but the original code won't. Adjusting the frames of your subviews in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is the correct way.

Comment: That was not my question. I was asking why the screen bounds were not applied to the imageView, not whether it'll change or not on rotation.

Comment: You just said the problem went away when you restarted xcode. So the screen bounds were actually applied. On top of that I'm just telling you that setting subview's frame in viewDidLoad is not a good practice anyway

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is give the full name of the jpg image:

```
backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "bg-img.jpg")
```

If it were placed in `Assets.xcassets`, or a `png` file, then specifying the extension would have been optional.

Sometimes all you need is to Clean your Build Folder <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, or just restart Xcode.

Comment: Extension is not mandatory. It should work without it. I didn't downvote btw.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that. My images are all probably png then.

Comment: @Carpsen90 I didn't know that either. That's cool! my image is .png tho... but that wasn't the problem tho. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: @Carpsen90 You don't need to write an extension for images from `Assets.xcassets`. Just tried it and `JPG` image was loaded fine.

Comment: @YuryImashev You've said it: "images from *Assets.xcassets*" not in the project in general.

Comment: @Carpsen90 Yeah, but OP wrote at the end of his post: *My image is inside the Assets.xcassets folder*

Comment: @YuryImashev touché!